# About $C^{0}$ being topological manifold

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, differential-topology

Is that the reason why $C^{0}$ being topological manifold due to that $C^{0}=\phi$ which contains nothing? Correct me if I am wrong. I am new to differential topology.

Comment: $C^0 $ contains the zero vector only.

Comment: I suggest reviewing the definitions of symbols before asking, and   including them in the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $C^0$ denotes the ring of continuous functions, as opposed to $C^k$, $k\ge 1$, which denotes functions with up to $k$th order derivatives continuous.